# Another Synergy issue: screen lock on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have set up Synergy on Unix systems with no problems, however when I set up a Synergy server on a Windows Server 2003 box using I get an error message that the mouse cursor is locked when trying to move to the client system.  I use a Microsoft Natural keyboard in case that matters (seems Scroll Lock might be involved).  Does anyone have experience with using Synergy on Windows systems that have reported mouse screen locking in the log when unable to mouse over to a client system?

Comment: You might want to open a new issue on the synergy-plus bug tracker, if you want to see this fixed. http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/entry

Answer (score 4):

Paul:  The Scroll-lock key is the "lock the mouse to this screen and don't let it leave" key.  you can change it off by adding this in the options section of the ~/.synergy.conf or /etc/synergy.conf

keystroke(f12) = lockCursorToScreen(toggle)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue - NOTE: cursor is locked to screen.

Tried lot of combination restarting the application. remove the monitor and added new monitors in configure server. but didn't work. i got answer from url - http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/fix-synergy-cursor-is-locked-to-screen-unable-to-move-from-one-monitor-to-another/

**Solution is simple. your main keyboard is "scroll Lock"ed. Unlock the "scroll Lock" by pressing Scroll Lock key in your keyboard. Simple**

Answer (score 0):

I run the Synergy server on my Mac and the client on both a Vista machine and a GNU/Linux (Gentoo) box. On the Vista box I notice that when the screen is locked I am unable to unlock it with the shared (Mac) keyboard. But with Gentoo, this works quite seamlessly. I am not sure what the solution is though and it'd be nice to find one.